# Do you prefer a Grid of ContentControl elements?

Tags: xaml, wpf-controls

Today I am led to say for the greatest level of flexibility using a `Grid` of `ContentControl` elements is the way to go. Are there any caveats coming for choosing this strategy? (Note that, of course, I am not referring to the `DataGrid` or the `GridView` of a `ListView`.)

Answer (score 0):

I think for layout it's best not to have an overall "preference", rather you should use the right tool for the job.

I use Grid, Canvas, Border, DockPanel and StackPanel everyday.  Each has their benefits and applications.  The more you play around with each, the easier it is for you to understand which you should in each circumstance.